# Android Studio 2.2 layout files have wrong information

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I upgraded android studio to 2.2 a little while ago and when I went to opened one of my projects all of my layout files are messed up along with some of my classes

for example one of my layout files looks like this in android studio

```
����   3�
 ��� actionBarDivider I 
ConstantValue E actionBarItemBackground F actionBarPopupTheme ? 
actionBarSize D actionBarSplitStyle A actionBarStyle @ actionBarTabBarStyle ; actionBarTabStyle : actionBarTabTextStyle < actionBarTheme B actionBarWidgetTheme C actionButtonStyle ` actionDropDownStyle \ actionLayout � actionMenuTextAppearance G actionMenuTextColor H actionModeBackground K actionModeCloseButtonStyle J actionModeCloseDrawable M actionModeCopyDrawable O actionModeCutDrawable N actionModeFindDrawable S actionModePasteDrawable P actionModePopupWindowStyle U actionModeSelectAllDrawable Q actionModeShareDrawable R actionModeSplitBackground L actionModeStyle I actionModeWebSearchDrawable T actionOverflowButtonStyle = actionOverflowMenuStyle > actionProviderClass � actionViewClass � activityChooserViewStyle h alertDialogButtonGroupStyle � alertDialogCenterButtons � alertDialogStyle � alertDialogTheme � 
allowStacking � alpha � arrowHeadLength � arrowShaftLength � autoCompleteTextViewStyle � 
background  backgroundSplit  backgroundStacked 
 backgroundTint@ backgroundTintModeA    barLength � borderlessButtonStyle e buttonBarButtonStyle b buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle � buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle � buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle � buttonBarStyle a 
buttonGravity5 buttonPanelSideLayout ! buttonStyle � buttonStyleSmall � 
buttonTint � buttonTintMode � 
checkboxStyle � checkedTextViewStyle �  closeIcon � closeItemLayout  collapseContentDescription7 collapseIcon6 color � colorAccent � colorBackgroundFloating � colorButtonNormal � colorControlActivated � colorControlHighlight � colorControlNormal � colorPrimary � colorPrimaryDark � colorSwitchThumbNormal � 
commitIcon � contentInsetEnd  contentInsetEndWithActions  contentInsetLeft  contentInsetRight  contentInsetStart  contentInsetStartWithNavigation  controlBackground � customNavigationLayout  defaultQueryHint � dialogPreferredPadding Z dialogTheme Y displayOptions  divider  dividerHorizontal g dividerPadding � dividerVertical f drawableSize � drawerArrowStyle   dropDownListViewStyle y dropdownListPreferredItemHeight ] editTextBackground n 
editTextColor m 
editTextStyle �     elevation  $expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable   gapBetweenBars � goIcon � height  hideOnContentScroll  homeAsUpIndicator _ 
homeLayout  icon     iconifiedByDefault � imageButtonStyle o indeterminateProgressStyle  initialActivityCount  isLightTheme  itemPadding  layout � listChoiceBackgroundIndicator � listDividerAlertDialog [ listItemLayout % 
listLayout " listMenuViewStyle � listPopupWindowStyle z listPreferredItemHeight t listPreferredItemHeightLarge v listPreferredItemHeightSmall u listPreferredItemPaddingLeft w listPreferredItemPaddingRight x logo
```

some layout files actually have code from my classes in them...

If I look at the xml files on disk the layout is correct (which is good news) along with the classes

has anyone else seen this problem and know how to fix it? Cleaning the project didnt do anything

Comment: How do the files look when opened in a text editor outside of Android Studio?

Comment: @BrendanL they look normal thankfully so I didnt lose any data

Comment: Please try `Invalidate Cache and Restart` if you haven't already.

Comment: @Shaishav ah that did it, I didnt know about that thank you!

Comment: Hmm...cool, mind if I post that as an answer?

Comment: sure can, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, this appears to be an issue where the file contents of a normal file cannot be rendered properly by the tool, I suggest to try following:

`File > Invalidate Cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart`

However, I do not understand the true cause for this issue. If you can reproduce the issue, you may want to file a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug).